# Short wavelength limit in Eikonal equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, geometric-optics, classical-field-theory

Limting the discourse of this question only for scalar waves in optics, we have
$\nabla^2 \phi - \dfrac{n^2}{c^2} \dfrac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} =0  $.

Now, when we investigate about geometric optics limit of it, the eikonal equation is taken into consideration. $\phi(\mathbf{r},t) = \phi_0(\mathbf{r},t) e^{f (\mathbf{r},n(\mathbf{r}))- \omega t}$.

Here, refractive index $n$ is assumed to be weakly changing over wavelength.
This requirement is translated into condition $\left | \nabla n(\mathbf{r}) \right | \ll | \mathbf{k} n(\mathbf{r})|$, where $\mathbf{k}= \dfrac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$.

It is also considered that amplitude $\phi_0$ is very slowly varying over wavelength, like in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/627749/52981) and therefore, $\left | \nabla \phi_0(\mathbf{r},t) \right | \ll | \mathbf{k} \phi_0(\mathbf{r},t) |$ .

I fail to understand "exactly" how this mathematical expressions come from. Can anyone explain intuitively how these expressions come ?

I undertsand that change in amplitude is given by $\nabla \phi_0$ but to indicate that change in amplitude is very small over wavelength - how it is $\left | \nabla \phi_0(\mathbf{r},t) \right | \ll | \mathbf{k} \phi_0(\mathbf{r},t) |$ ?

Comment: see this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/762692/how-to-calculate-the-intensity-of-a-light-when-using-the-ray-model/762719#762719 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744145/what-exactly-is-a-analytical-ray-tracer-in-a-physical-sense/744159#744159

Answer (score 2):

> I fail to understand "exactly" how this mathematical expressions come from.
> Can anyone explain intuitively how these expressions come ?

When changing position by $\Delta\mathbf{r}$,
the amplitude $\phi_0$ changes by
$$\Delta\phi_0 = \nabla\phi_0\cdot\Delta\mathbf{r} \tag{1}$$

Expanding the scalar product we get
$$\Delta\phi_0 = |\nabla\phi_0|\ |\Delta\mathbf{r}|\ \cos\alpha  \tag{2}$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between $\nabla\phi_0$ and $\Delta\mathbf{r}$.

Saying "the amplitude is slowly varying over a wavelength" just means:
For $|\Delta\mathbf{r}|=\lambda$ the amplitude changes only
by a small percentage, i.e.
$$\Delta\phi_0 \ll \phi_0 \tag{3}$$

Using this together with (2) we get
$$|\nabla\phi_0|\ \lambda\ \cos\alpha \ll \phi_0 \tag{4}$$
and with $|\mathbf{k}|=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$
$$|\nabla\phi_0|\ \cos\alpha \ll \frac{|\mathbf{k}|}{2\pi} \phi_0$$

Since we are only interested in orders of magnitude,
we can neglect the factors $\cos\alpha$ and $2\pi$
(their order of magnitude is $\approx 1$)
$$|\nabla\phi_0| \ll |\mathbf{k}|\ \phi_0 \tag{5}$$

You can do the same reasoning like above for the amplitude $\phi_0$
also for the refractive index $n$.